# glassfish cluster fail at start

Tags: cluster, glassfish

I got a problem trying to set a cluster up.

I'm gonna describe detailed configuration(since I couldn't find a cluster example made on
two different pcs, all of them were made on one localhost):

3 ubuntu virtual machines: 1 domain administrator and 2 instances.

I installed(unziped) 1 glassfish server on each instanace and started them.
Then I created a ssh node for each one on the domain administrator(also a glassfish)

So I have

> node1 192.168.193.134 SSH node 
>   node2 192.168.193.133 SSH node

both successfully connected.

Finally I created the cluster through the command line like this

> :~$ asadmin create-cluster clusterm 
>  
>   :~$ asadmin create-instance --node node1 --cluster clusterm inst1 
>   :~$ asadmin create-instance --node node2 --cluster clusterm inst2

but when I tried to start the cluster up (`:~$ asadmin start-cluster clusterm`) it failed throwing this error:

```
    remote failure: inst1: Could not start instance inst1 on node node1 (192.168.193.134).

    Command failed on node node1 (192.168.193.134): Previous synchronization failed at May 20, 2013 12:16:45 AM
    Will perform full synchronization.
    Removing all cached state for instance inst1.
    Command start-local-instance failed.
    CLI802 Synchronization failed for directory config, caused by:
      remote failure: Unknown server instance: inst1

    To complete this operation run the following command locally on host 192.168.193.134 from the GlassFish install location /opt/glassfish3:

     bin/asadmin  start-local-instance --node node1 --sync normal inst1
    inst2: Could not start instance inst2 on node node2 (192.168.193.133).

    Command failed on node node2 (192.168.193.133): Previous synchronization failed at May 20, 2013 12:18:09 AM
    Will perform full synchronization.
    Removing all cached state for instance inst2.
    CLI802 Synchronization failed for directory config, caused by:
      remote failure: Unknown server instance: inst2
    Command start-local-instance failed.

    To complete this operation run the following command locally on host 192.168.193.133 from the GlassFish install location /opt/glassfish3:

     bin/asadmin  start-local-instance --node node2 --sync normal inst2

    The command start-instance failed for: inst1 inst2 
    Command start-cluster failed.
```

I would thank you helping me on figure out why this happens(or what I did wrong).

Comment: any update on that ? as I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must run

```
asadmin start-local-instance --node node2 --sync normal i1
```

then you can stop instance and run again cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but I had the same problem and spend some time on it.

In my case I had to modify the */path/to/node/agent/config/das.properties* file for each node.

Changing values shoud do the trick

```
agent.das.port=das_port
agent.das.host=das_hostname
```